# How to control UPS via nut rather than gnome-power-manager?

Tags: gnome-power-manager, ups, hal

I am trying to control my CyberPower 625VA UPS.  From what I hear, this is best done via nut, rather than via the gnome-power-manager.  See e.g. [Monitoring a UPS with nut on Debian or Ubuntu Linux | Random Bits](http://blog.shadypixel.com/monitoring-a-ups-with-nut-on-debian-or-ubuntu-linux/)

But when I configure nut as described in that article, it fails:

```
$ sudo upsdrvctl start
Network UPS Tools - UPS driver controller 2.4.3
Network UPS Tools - Generic HID driver 0.34 (2.4.3)
USB communication driver 0.31
Can't claim USB device [0764:0501]: could not detach kernel driver from interface 0: Operation not permitted
Driver failed to start (exit status=1)
```

I then noted that it was already being monitored by gnome-power-manager.  The article (presumably now out-of-date) had said I would need to install `nut-hal-drivers` in order to monitor it with the Gnome Power Manager, so I hadn't even looked up there on the indicator panel....   But it wasn't being monitored very well (both the History and Statistics tabs were useless), and what I really want is programmatic control.

I do note that I can get some raw battery data via

```
lshal -u /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_764_501_noserial_if0_hiddev
```

But I'd prefer nut.

So how to I tell the power manager to NOT monitor the UPS, so nut will (presumably)?

FWIW, this situation is the same on both maverick and precise, on laptops in both cases.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same question.  Anyone have any info?

Comment: @AShelly What release are you running?  What are your symptoms?

Comment: @nealmcb has this problem been solved or are you no longer on `maverick` or `precise` and the problem went away on its own?

Comment: Thanks for the followup, @WinEunuuchs2Unix. I'm not using that UPS any more, so can't test to see if it is still there.

Comment: I'll vote to close it as not reproducible then. Thanks for letting me know.